# How to set true to object in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to set true or false depending passing values but not working in angular 8.If anyone know please help to resolev this issue.

When one is set to true, I want all the others to be set to false as well.

app.component.ts:

```js
this.main = { 
    power: false,
    electrical: false,
    wire: false,
    current: false
}

testing(flag){ 
    this.main[flag]=true;
}

testing(wire);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All others answesr is working but I was thinking about a new way

```js
  main = {
    power: false,
    electrical: false,
    wire: false,
    current: false
  };

  flagsValues = null;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.flagsValues = {
      ...this.main
    };
  }

  testing(flag) {
    this.flagsValues = {
      ...this.main,  // object spread
      [flag]: true  //overwrite passed falg with true
    };
  }
```

[demo ⚡](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ri99wp)

with Object.assign

```js
  testing(flag) {
    this.flagsValues = Object.assign({},this.main)
    this.flagsValues[flag] = true; 
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're inside a component class, `wire` is not defined when you call `testing`. It needs to be a string to work. Also, you're using `this` wrong. Try:

```js
main = { 
  power: false,
  electrical: false,
  wire: false,
  current: false
}

testing(flag){ 
  this.main[flag] = true;
}
```

Then somewhere inside another function of the same component:

```
this.testing("wire");
```

**UPDATE**: From what I understand, you want a function that sets 1 property to `true` and the rest to `false`. Try this:

```js
testing(flag) {
  for(let key in this.main) {
    this.main[key] = key == flag;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qczxwr) to showcase.

Comment: How to set others like false? From the object only one will be true others should be false

Comment: You want to set them all to `true` in one function call?

Comment: i want to set only one will be true others should be false..example this.testing("power") thia.main.power will be true others should be false

Comment: @NilaVaani It should work, perhaps you're calling it wrongly. Please see the stackblitz I added.

Comment: good job  but I was thing  we just change one key , so we can just keep the main and clone the values and just chane the new one , chck my answer as just another way 

Answer (score 2):

Put your key in between quotes `""` or `''` .

For example

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
 name = 'Angular';
 main = { 
  power: false,
  electrical: false,
  wire: false,
  current: false
 }

 constructor(){
  this.testing('wire');
 }

 testing(flag){ 
  //this.main[flag]=true;
  Object.keys(this.main).map( key => {
    this.main[key] = key === flag ?  true : false; 
  })
 }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>wire - {{main.wire}}</p>
<p>power - {{main.power}}</p>
<p>electrical - {{main.electrical}}</p>
<p>current - {{main.current}}</p>
```

See working example here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzq8ju?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: How to set others should be false?

Comment: @NilaVaani, I am updating the answer and link. please check it.

Comment: the `?  true : false` part is redundent, as `===` will return true or false accordingly already.

Answer (score 1):

```
main={ 
power:false,
electrical:false,
wire:false,
current:false
}

testing(flag){ 
Object.keys(this.main).map( key => {
    this.main[key] = key === flag ?  true : false; 
  })
}

this.testing('wire');
```

Please try like this

Please check on
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzq8ju

Comment: Thanks..But how to set others like false?

Comment: you need to set true false dynamically?